404 error with Vue.js router when deploying on Apache server
I am deploying an admin panel for an ecommerce site built with Vue.js on a web server with Apache. I am encountering the classic 404 error when refreshing the page. The directory structure is as shown in the image.

I created the .conf file with the following content
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName pannel.takfibra.com
    ServerAdmin info@fabioangelici.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/takfibraec/vuejs-admin/dist

    <Directory /var/www/takfibraec/vuejs-admin/dist>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteBase /
            RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =pannel.takfibra.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

I suspect that the error is in this file, but not being an expert, I can't figure out what the problem is.

Check the comment from the Staging Ground. Otherwise, I recommend not spending too much time on such a thing and rather deploy it to Netlify or Cloudflare pages. You'll have better performance and an easier time doing the whole thing.

If you are using VueJS 3 then you will need to make sure that you have following in your router file.
{
    path: '/:pathMatch(.*)*',
    name: 'not-found',
    component: SomeComponent,
    meta: {
        title: 'Error',
    },
}

and then you can use following conf file
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    ServerLimit 1
    StartServers 1
    MinSpareThreads 25
    MaxSpareThreads 75
    ThreadsPerChild 25
    MaxRequestWorkers 25
    MaxConnectionsPerChild 0
</IfModule>

# Error Log
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error.log
LogLevel warn

# Event Configuration
<IfModule worker.c>
    ThreadLimit 1024
</IfModule>

# HTTP Configuration
<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
    DefaultType application/octet-stream
</IfModule>

# Log Format
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" \"%{X-Forwarded-For}i\"" main
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access.log main

# Server Configuration
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /app

    <Directory /app>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
        DirectoryIndex index.html
    </Directory>

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]
    </IfModule>

    ErrorDocument 500 /50x.html
    ErrorDocument 502 /50x.html
    ErrorDocument 503 /50x.html
    ErrorDocument 504 /50x.html

    <Files "50x.html">
        ErrorDocument 500 /usr/share/httpd/noindex/50x.html
        ErrorDocument 502 /usr/share/httpd/noindex/50x.html
        ErrorDocument 503 /usr/share/httpd/noindex/50x.html
        ErrorDocument 504 /usr/share/httpd/noindex/50x.html
    </Files>

    # Other configurations for keep-alive and sendfile
    KeepAlive On
    KeepAliveTimeout 65
    EnableSendfile On
</VirtualHost>

That should work. However, I would recommend to use nginx if you can. For more information you can visit. https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#docker-nginx

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
